# How to find Full region coordinates by using particular area name in Google maps api

Tags: php, jquery, google-maps

How can we get coordinates of an area by giving the name in Google map API in Php? For example, if I search Washington, DC, USA then Google map give me area coordinate of this.Any method available in Google map API in PHP?

Answer (score 0):

Given the location "Washington, DC, USA", you can do the following for a quick way:

```
$map_address = "Washington, DC, USA";

$url = "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?sensor=false&address=".urlencode($map_address);
$geocodeVars = get_object_vars(json_decode(file_get_contents($url)));

$latitude = $geocodeVars['results'][0]->geometry->location->lat;
$longitude = $geocodeVars['results'][0]->geometry->location->lng;
```

So, you can now use `$latitude` and `$longitude`.